# Finding the conjugacy classes of $S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm having difficulty in understanding *how* the conjugacy classes are calculated in $S_{3}$.

I know they are $\{e\}, \{(12),(13),(23)\}$ and $\{(123),(132)\}$ but do not know how to show for the latter two.

For $(12)$ in $S_{3}$, to find the conjugacy class, I know any conjugate will have
the form $(g(1) g(2))$ where $g$ is the conjugating element. But the notes I have go on to say this: $(12)^{(23)} = ((23) · 1 (23) · 2) = (13)$ and $(12)^{(123)} = (23)$.

I can't understand why these calculations are done and what they mean and wondered if anyone could explain what is happening in this line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the caclulations are done, but the notation $(12)^{(23)}$ means that $(12)$ is conjugated by $(23)$, i.e. $(12)^{(23)} = (23)(12)(23)^{-1}$. I guess you can perform the composition of the cycles now and determine the value.

On the other hand in $S_n$ we have that two elements are conjugates iff they have the same kind of disjoint cycles. This means that the elements of the form $(a_1,a_2)$ are in one conjugacy class, while $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ are in other.

Comment: @harry55 This claim in the second paragraph isn't very hard to prove, but if you insist I can write the proof, although I recommend you to try it on your own if you're not familiar with it already.

Comment: I understand the claim in the second paragraph and its proof. I am now clearer on the line I needed help with but still don't quite understand why we pick $(23)$ in $(12)^{(23)}$ and then $(123)$ in $(12)^{(123)}$. Why do we not pick $(12)$ to be conjugated by $(132)$ or $(13)$? And why does doing this show that all 2 cycles conjugate? Simply because they are the same kind of disjoint cycles? If so why couldn't we just state this in the first place and read off the answer from the elements in $S_{n}$.? Sorry these may seem silly questions but I'm struggling to get my head round it.

Comment: @harry55 There's no particular reason for choosing the element. In fact it doesn't show anything, as you need to conjugate an element by all the elements of the group. I guess the person who gave you the notes, just checked few elements and skipped the others.